# Service Worker giving out old version of itself

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

For some reason my Service Worker seems to be delivering an outdated version of itself.

So, basically, when I rebuild the website the `PROJECT.buildhash` gets a new generated random string, which is then used to set the CACHE version.

The most recent cache version is the only one that gets added to the whitelist array.

Notice how I in the `activate` event listener, right at the bottom, use `console.log` to show what version of the cache is currently activated and serving files. It keeps giving me old versions of the service worker version number.

So when I build the website a sw.js file is generated which controls the service worker. I browser to the site and it's installed. Now I rebuild the website with some changes to the code, but when I update the site the service worker doesn't get updated.

The only way for me to update the worker is by deleting the cache completely.

```
/* global caches, Promise, fetch, PROJECT, self */

'use strict';

var CACHE = {
    version: PROJECT.version + "-" + PROJECT.buildhash,
    resources: [
        '/index.html'
    ]
};

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE.version).then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll(CACHE.resources);
    })
            );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function (resp) {
        return resp || fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
            return caches.open(CACHE.version).then(function (cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Could not add to cache!' + error);
                });
                return response;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Could not open cache!' + error);
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Resource not found!' + error);
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Resource not found in the cache!' + error);
    })
            );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    var cacheWhitelist = [CACHE.version];
    event.waitUntil(
            caches.keys().then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
            if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                return caches.delete(key);
            }
        }));
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Cache version " + CACHE.version + " was activated.");
    }));
});
```

Comment: if this is just debug scenario -devtools- and u need to force a reload of the worker , u can ..  hard refresh with rightClik on the reload button forces new SW and will put in in "uninstalled" state . from there you can navigate away and back and will have the new SW

Answer (score 0):

You might need to implement [clients.claim()](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#clientsclaim) and [self.skipWaiting()](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase) in your service worker for your changes to take effect. There is more about updating your service worker [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates).

Another possibility is that the service worker won't update unless the service worker response from the server changes. Is it possible you're doing any server side caching that might prevent your new service worker version from being updated? You can try hitting the file directly and making sure the cache name is correct.